# Ubuntu for tablet

Tags: tablet

I have a Samsung Galaxy note 10.1.  I am interested in converting the Os to Ubuntu.   When you have a beta version, I would love to trial it.  Thanks Lee

Comment: The [Ubuntu Wiki on Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Supported_devices_and_codenames) does not list your device to be supported, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Samsung Galaxy Note 10.01 is not officially supported and thus will not work good.

Secondly, yes, there is a development version, but it's not that easy to install at the moment and I do not recommend using it for daily use purposes.

Here is a list of devices, which are being worked upon. You will also find relative forum link where you can post queries.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

**[this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Riw3ybLYKSs)** will show you how to install it on your Galaxy Note.